# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{k+1}-2k\left(\ln{(k+1)}-\ln{(k)}\right)=\ln{\left(2 \pi \right)}-1-\gamma$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k+1}{k+1}-2k\left(\ln{(k+1)}-\ln{(k)}\right)=\ln{\left(2 \pi \right)}-1-\gamma$$
This is for $\int_0^1 \{ \frac{1}{x} \} ^2 \; \mathrm{d}x$
Furthest I got for the series was
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} 2t-2t\ln{(t+1)}-\sum_{k=1}^{t} \frac{1}{k+1}-2\ln{k}$$
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

I notice the series here evaluates to 1/2 of what the series in my question does.  Can we manipulate my series into this one some how?

Comment: This problem is  same as that of  [AMM 12194](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/amm.html) published issue and which is a classical problem too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, $k(\ln(k+1)-\ln k)=(k+1)\ln(k+1)-k\ln k-\ln(k+1)$, thus
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k(\ln(k+1)-\ln k)=(n+1)\ln(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k+1)=(n+1)\ln(n+1)-\ln((n+1)!) $$
And
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+1}{k+1}=2n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+1}=2n+1-H_{n+1} $$
Using $H_n=\ln n+\gamma+o(1)$ and Stirling formula $\ln(n!)=n\ln n-n+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+\frac{1}{2}\ln n+o(1)$, we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{2k+1}{k+1}-2k(\ln(k+1)-\ln k)\right]=\ln(2\pi)-\gamma-1+o(1) $$
Letting $n\rightarrow +\infty$ gives the desired equality.